# How to interpret at() function; substr() function; occurs() function in a pseudo-code

Tags: php, c++, sql, pseudocode

I recently had this question for a job pre-assessment and I didn't know how to solve it even after looking up how each function works. It was a pseudo-code.

Below is a function called `foo()`, which is passed a value, and returns a value.  What would the return of the foo function be if it were passed the following value?

`foo("JOHN PAUL SMITH")`

The function is as below:

```
function foo 
parameter p1   

if occurs(' ', p1) > 1     
   m.ReturnValue = substr(p1, at(' ', p1, 2) + 1)   
else if occurs(' ', p1) = 1        
   m.ReturnValue = substr(p1, at(' ', p1, 1) + 1)     
else 
   m.ReturnValue = p1   
  
endif 
  
endif 
   
return m.ReturnValue
```

My interpretation is, it would go to the first `IF` statement since the char is longer than 1 character. Then, that IF statement would remove the 2nd set of characters, which would be the middle name, but I don't feel as though that would be correct because I'm not sure what the `+1` before the ending of the parentheses does in the following line:

`m.ReturnValue = substr(p1, at(' ', p1, 2) + 1)`

Could someone explain how to work through interpreting this snippet of pseudo-code and let me know if I am on the correct path so that I understand it for the next time? And I am also not sure which language they correspond to.

Comment: Please only add one language tag.

Comment: It's possible that the +1 is because ranges are often written in a way that the lower bound is included and the upper bound is excluded. So that could signify a substring that includes up to the second occurrence of `' '`, but not anything beyond it. EDIT: Actually, in C++, the behavior of substr would be to start at the given argument and continue to the end of the string. So it would return everything after, and not including, the second instance of `' '`.

Comment: And this is defienetelly `C` not `C++`. `substr ()` in `C++` would be part of `string` class.

Comment: This is not C++ either.

Comment: This is not valid C or C++. Not even close. I don't know what language it is, but It is neither of those.

Comment: @Aganju I know, but based on function style it looks more like it.

Comment: @mmackliet it is pseudo_code

Comment: Whatever it is, it appears to want to return the last word in the string, whether that be word 3, word 2 or the first and only word.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed the tag to "pseudo_code" and took C++ out of the heading

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what if there is 4 spaces? it will return last two words if I am not mistaking.

Comment: `if occurs(' ',p1) > 1` handles as many spaces as you have, `f occurs(' ',p1) = 1` handles a single space and `else` handles no space.

Comment: So, the "job pre-assessment" question was "guess the semantics of this programming language from a code snippet"? No, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, this is a pseudo-code, so the functions `at()`, `substr()`, `occurs()` don't need to be present in real.
- But, it is the primary duty of a good interviewer to clarify the behavior of every unknown functions in the pseudo-code or at least mention the language those functions correspond to. That is because, the function for finding substring in `JavaScript`, `c++`, `php` works similarly, but they always don't accept same no. of parameters. On the other hand, `charAt()` or `at()` functions are in several languages, but they can have different types of parameters.
- Anyway, let us try to find out the definitions of those unknown functions. Currently, from my knowledge, I can determine that those functions mentioned in the pseudo-code closely match with that of `MySQL` definition of `SUBSTR()` and `SQL` definition of `CHARINDEX()` function, which I have guessed from the no. of arguments passed and their type.

In `MySQL` and `SQL` respectively, those 2 functions are defined as:

```
SUBSTR(string, start, length)           // length is optional here
CHARINDEX(substring, string, start)     // start is optional here
```

Now, let us divide different sections of the pseudo-code as you posted:

- `occurs(' ', p1)` is easily understandable. It will return how many space characters are present within passed parameter string `p1`. In given string `"JOHN PAUL SMITH"`, we can clearly see 2 space characters. Then, `if occurs(' ', p1) > 1` will return true and this line- `m.ReturnValue = substr(p1, at(' ', p1, 2) + 1)` will execute.
- Now, if we try to correspond `at(' ', p1, 2)` with sql `CHARINDEX(substring, string, start)`, it will mean that starting from index 2 (assuming 1-based index), it will search for the first occurrence of space character and return that index. So, in this case of given string `"JOHN PAUL SMITH"`, it should return `5` (considering 1-based index).
- If we try to correspond `substr(p1, SOMETHING)` with MySQL `SUBSTR(string, start, [length])`, here `length` being the optional, and as we have already found the `at()` function returns `5`, so the expression will be evaluate to `m.ReturnValue = substr(p1, 5 + 1)`
- Finally, the function returns `m.ReturnValue` and if we find the substring from the 6th index (considering 1-based index) of the given string, our final output to the interviewer would be: **PAUL SMITH**

**Edit:**

Whatever I have already explained, there could have one confusion regarding `at()` function, specifically its 3rd parameters. Other 2 functions are clear. As I mentioned earlier that, if it would correspond to `SQL`, then 3rd parameter would be the starting point. But, there could have other case, the 3rd parameter could be mentioned as `occurrence_num`. In that case, as `2` is passed as the parameter, the `at(' ', p1, 2)` will return `10` (considering 1-based index). Subsequently, final answer will be `substr(p1, 10 + 1)` i.e. `substr(p1, 11)` i.e. **SMITH**.

Comment: _After more analysis, I guess this edited part of my answer is more acceptable._ However, I am pretty sure that your interviewer has already mentioned the parameters of those functions, otherwise it is not only difficult but also impossible to answer that question. And, if the interviewer didn't mention them, then there is no point of doing job for that company.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding this pseudo-code checks how many spaces are in given string. If there is more than one it returns substring beyond second space character, if one space that it returns substring beyond that one space otherwise it returns whole string (meaning no space ins tring). So if you have this input:

> I am home.

it will return *home.*

> I am home now.

it will return *home now.*

> Goodbye now.

it will return *now.*

> Goodbye.

it will just return *Goodbye.*

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all of the help and insight on this!
I found some documentation and both of the answers given were correct.

In written pseudo-code the function given can be interpreted as such:

```
function foo 
parameter p1 //which is equal to "JOHN PAUL SMITH" in this case 

if (p1 has more than 1 occurrence of " " [i.e. more than 1 spaces])     
   ReturnValue = everything after the 2nd " " in p1  

else if (p1 only has 1 occurrence of " " [i.e. 1 space])      
   ReturnValue = everything after the 1st " " within p1   
  
else //[i.e. no spaces]
   ReturnValue =  p1   
  
endif 
  
endif 
   
return ReturnValue
```

So the function should return: **SMITH**